# CSS margin and padding correct implemntaion for headings

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently I have a debate with my team mates regarding css heading margin and padding. I am a big fan of **boostrap** and tend to follow their guideline and the way treat padding and margin with heading. The conflict is between wether heading (h1, h2, h3 ect...) should have margin-top or padding at all.

[image]

**Example A** is from bootstrap with margin and padding for heading, for **Example B** is our business website no margin top only bottom. Their point of view is reduce the chance having extra top margin and the margin should defined by the container. But for bootstrap grid system, the default padding-top and padding-bottom is 0px, so it make sense to adding margin to the heading to create the top margin.

So what's the correct and best approach for heading?

1. Container with padding and heading with no margin-top
2. Container with no padding top and bottom, heading with margin and padding.

Please let me know. Thanks

Note: **Foundation** follow the same rule only padding-left and padding-right for default.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em)
.column, .columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: personally, I do Option B, for me it's easier to create equal line spacing(flow) for the content.

Comment: hmm... do you use bootstrap? their container default is padding-top and padding-bottom 0px, so are you overwrite their default by adding padding: 15px? Event foundation css framework doing the same thing.